# Unable to add users to Public Group

Tags: user-management, public-group, delegated-admin

I have created a Delegated Admin Group and add few users to this group. The Delegated Admins have access to a Public Group. This should allow them to add users to the Public Group.

Some of the users are able to see the option to add Users, Roles, etc to the Public Group. However, other users only see the option to add other Public Groups (See screen shots below). I have checked the permissions for these users and as far as I can see they have the same permissions - same profile, roles, permission sets.

What should I check to allow Delegated Admins to add individual users to a Public Group?

[image: Only option is to add public group]

[image: Includes option to add users]

Comment: do the delegated admins who can't add users to groups have the Manage Users permission?

Comment: Hi - thank you for that pointer. Adding Manager Users permission resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include `Manage Users` permission for those users in the delegated admins.  This is described in this help article [Create and Edit Groups](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/creating_and_editing_groups.htm)

You should be aware that `Manage Users` [grants permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324398&type=1&mode=1) that go way beyond creating/editing groups and you should think carefully about whether to grant such a permission to delegated admins. The permissions include access to configurations that affect record sharing so a malicious (or clueless) delegated admin could open up record visibility to users who shouldn't get it.